# Mechanical, not voltage driven electron motion creating larger net electromagnetic force

Tags: magnetic-fields

Have mercy I'm a physician not a physicist.

Electrons' Motion in an electromagnet is on the order of 10$^{-4}$ m/s. That charge can be mechanically rotated in a capacitor with a million times more velocity (B produced being proportional to charge's velocity ).

Forces causing eddy currents would help  to negate net magnetic field in an ordinary capacitor. However, if radially oriented, unidirectionally conducting (" chair " ) carbon nanotubes are rotated, the electrons would be relatively constrained from eddy currents.

It seems like this would allow greater magnetic field production compared to standard electromagnets.

Doable?

Comment: So, in short, are you proposing rotating charged carbon nanotubes to create a magnetic field?

Comment: The "little" problem with your suggestion is that the charge that can be moved this way is some 12 orders of magnitude smaller than the charge that is moving in the conductor, so your suggestion ends up six orders of magnitude short.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand you are proposing moving electrons mechanically rather than with some sort of electromotive force to make an electromagnet.

Say we have a little electromagnet maybe 5 cm long with 100 loops of wire and we run 0.25 A of current through it.  With an air core we should get a magnetic field inside or about 1 millitesla ([handy caluclator](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/solenoid.html#c3)).

Now, what if we wanted to do that with a rotating static charge?  You are proposing moving it a million times faster than $10^{-4}$m/s so 100 m/s.

In our solenoid we are using the same current 100 times to produce the magnetic field, effectively it's like a 25 A current going around a loop once.  We need to get the equivalent of a 25 amp current by swinging some charges around.  Current is the rate of charge flow, $I = q/\Delta t$, so we need to estimate $\Delta t$ which will depend on the radius or rotation - let's say, arbitrarily, 1 cm.  So, $\Delta d \simeq 6$cm which gives $\Delta t \simeq 6 \times 10^{-4}$s.  And, when we solve for $q$ we get 0.015 coulombs.  **This is not a small amount of static charge** to produce a modest magnetic field.  (Remember those van de Graaff generators from physics class that made your hair stand up - that had a charge in the order of 0.000 005 C.)  And that, I think, is where your problem is going to be.